# Extracting User Story from Commit Message in Jenkins

Tags: regex, jenkins, rally

I'm using the ext-email extension to extract the User Story which is added as a commit message to include in the mail body.

This is the console output:

> Commit message: "US285568"

I used the Build Log Excerpt method of the ext-email plug-in as follows:

> STORY: ${BUILD_LOG_EXCERPT, start="Commit message:\ \"", end="\'"}

However, this does not match anything and I'm not able to understand why it's failing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find a proper documentation for this plug-in.

I used a work-around solution by triggering a helper job at the end of the current job (which contains the commit message in the console output).

I am executing the following shell code in the helper job:

```
result=$(curl -GET {JENKINS_IP}/jenkins/job/{UPSTREAM_JOB_NAME}/consoleFull --user "user:pass")

comm=$(grep "Commit message:" <<< "$result")


if grep -E "US[0-9]+" <<< "$comm"
then
    final=$(grep -o "US[0-9]*" <<< "$comm")
else
    final="<font color=\"red\">User Story not found</font>"
fi

echo FINAL=$final > env.properties
```

To access the FINAL variable (which contains the value of the user story) as an environment variable, I have used the [EnvInject plug-in](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin).

To access the FINAL variable outside the shell code in the job, add the "Inject environment variables" build step after the shell code and enter "env.properties" in the Properties File Path.